# Why does this code returns "true"?

Tags: php, string, validation

I have some weird situation with following code:

```
$string = '///';
var_dump(!stripos($string, '//'));
```

This code section returns `true`. Now take a look at next code section:

```
$string = 'a//';
var_dump(!stripos($string, '//'));
```

This code section returns `false`.
At my opinion fisrt example should return `false` too, but it isn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do a `var_dump(!stripos($string, '//')); ` and you'll see that it return 0 and `!0` is true.

Comment: @MrTux, yup, you are right :) I totally forgot about it, thank you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stripos` returns the position of the first match for the string.

In the first case, that is the first character of the start (position 0), and in the second it is the second character (position 1).

`!` converts to a boolean and inverts it.

`0` is false so `!0` is true.

`1` is true so `!1` is false.